# .net store item and price in array

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multidimensional-array

I need to store an item and its corresponding price into an array and then display these.

E.g.
book at 10.00
chocolate bar at 0.85

I will populate the item and price into a dropdown. On a button click event I want to add these selections into an array.

How would I go about doing this in vb.net?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItem" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="12.49">book</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="14.99">music</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="0.85">chocolate bar</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="10.00">box of chocolates 1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="47.50">bottle of perfume 1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="27.99">bottle of perfume 2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="18.99">bottle of perfume</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="9.75">headache pills</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="11.25">box of chocolates 2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The code in the button click event seems to always overwrite what I initially added.

```
 Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

        'Add items into an array list
        Dim Item As String = ddlItem.SelectedItem.Text
        Dim Price As Decimal = ddlItem.SelectedValue

        Dim ListItemCollection As ListItemCollection = New ListItemCollection

        ListItemCollection.Add(Item)

        Response.Write(ListItemCollection.Count)

    End Sub
```

Comment: To tell you the truth I do not understand what you can't do. You speak here for client side or server side ?

Comment: I want to do this server side. I'm just not sure how to implement this.

Comment: You won to save that in an array in memory or on database ? This array must follow the user ? Its unclear.

Comment: I want to keep it simple and store in memory just for that session.

Comment: just wondering on what happens when you have 2 items with same price. You should put the id of the book item in the value and then get the price of the book item with the id.

Comment: No for the purpose of this example you can't add the same item twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server side / code behind, you should be able to access your DropDownList by name; `ddlItem`.

The `ddlItem.Items` [member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items.aspx) exposes a [ListItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.aspx), which in turn implements [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx).

IEnumerable has a [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx).  Therefore, it should be as simple as `ddlItem.Items.ToArray()`.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**

Having read your comment, I understand I may have misread your question.  The answer is still pretty simple though, code as shown:

```
Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim selectedItems = ddlItem.Items.Where(Function(n) n.Selected).ToArray()
    Response.Write(selectedItems.Count)
End Sub
```

Comment: @Rajeev - was your code up originally?  I seem to have made a lot more sense of it having read your question a second time.  Either way, I've edited my answer with a code snippet that find the selected items and then outputs the count as shown in your example.  Hope that helps.